# Android autofill service save request on sensitive data

Tags: java, android, autofill

I'm trying to give the user the option to save their passwords after registering on a website, using the autofill service provided by android.

```
List<FillContext> contexts = request.getFillContexts();
AssistStructure structure = contexts.get(contexts.size() - 1).getStructure();
ParsedStructure parsedStructure = ParsedStructure.parse(structure);
parsedStructure.getPasswordView().getText().toString()
```

This code is in the onSaveRequest method of Android's AutofillService.

When I log the last line, the text in the console only contains asterix characters and not the password itself. Does anyone have an idea why that is and an solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

AS most of the browsers are in Compatibility mode and do not support the native autofill api yet.
Read more at the android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/autofill/AutofillService#CompatibilityMode).